# Need serious help on creating a comet with animations in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I'm currently working on a SpriteKit project and need to create a comet with a fading tail that animates across the screen. I am having serious issues with SpriteKit in this regards.

**Attempt 1**. It:

1. Draws a CGPath and creates an SKShapeNode from the path
2. Creates a square SKShapeNode with gradient
3. Creates an SKCropNode and assigns its maskNode as line, and adds square as a child
4. Animates the square across the screen, while being clipped by the line/SKCropNode

   ```
   func makeCometInPosition(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint, color: UIColor, timeInterval: NSTimeInterval) {
           ... (...s are (definitely) irrelevant lines of code)
           let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
           ...
           let line = SKShapeNode(path:path)
           line.lineWidth = 1.0
           line.glowWidth = 1.0

           var squareFrame = line.frame
           ...
           let square = SKShapeNode(rect: squareFrame)
           //Custom SKTexture Extension. I've tried adding a normal image and the leak happens either way. The extension is not the problem
           square.fillTexture = SKTexture(color1: UIColor.clearColor(), color2: color, from: from, to: to, frame: line.frame)

           square.fillColor = color
           square.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
           square.zPosition = 1.0

           let maskNode = SKCropNode()
           maskNode.zPosition = 1.0
           maskNode.maskNode = line
           maskNode.addChild(square)

           //self is an SKScene, background is an SKSpriteNode
           self.background?.addChild(maskNode)

           let lineSequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(timeInterval), SKAction.removeFromParent()])

           let squareSequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1), SKAction.moveBy(CoreGraphics.CGVectorMake(deltaX * 2, deltaY * 2), duration: timeInterval), SKAction.removeFromParent()])

           square.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(squareSequence))
           maskNode.runAction(lineSequence)
           line.runAction(lineSequence)
       }
   ```

   This **works**, as shown below. 
   [image]

The problem is that after 20-40 other nodes come on the screen, weird things happen. Some of the nodes on the screen disappear, some stay. Also, the fps and node count (toggled in the SKView and **never** changed)

```
self.showsFPS = true
self.showsNodeCount = true
```

**disappear** from the screen. This makes me assume it's a bug with SpriteKit. SKShapeNode [has been known to cause issues](http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html).

**Attempt 2.** I tried changing square from an SKShapeNode to an SKSpriteNode (Adding and removing lines related to the two as necessary)

```
let tex = SKTexture(color1: UIColor.clearColor(), color2: color, from:    from, to: to, frame: line.frame)
let square = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
```

the rest of the code is basically identical. This produces a similar effect with no bugs performance/memory wise. However, something odd happens with SKCropNode and it looks like this
[image]

It has no antialiasing, and the line is thicker. I have tried changing anti-aliasing, glow width, and line width. There is a minimum width that can not change for some reason, and setting the glow width larger does this
[image]
. According to other stackoverflow questions maskNodes are either 1 or 0 in alpha. This is confusing since the SKShapeNode can have different line/glow widths.

**Attempt 3.** After some research, I discovered I might be able to use the clipping effect and preserve line width/glow using an SKEffectNode instead of SKCropNode.

```
    //Not the exact code to what I tried, but very similar
    let maskNode = SKEffectNode()
    maskNode.filter = customLinearImageFilter
    maskNode.addChild(line)
```

This produced the (literally) exact same effect as attempt 1. It created the same lines and animation, but the same bugs with other nodes/fps/nodeCount occured. So it seems to be a bug with SKEffectNode, and not SKShapeNode.

**I do not know how to bypass the bugs with attempt 1/3 or 2.**

Does anybody know if there is something I am doing wrong, if there is a bypass around this, or a different solution altogether for my problem?

Edit: I considered emitters, but there could potentially be hundreds of comets/other nodes coming in within a few seconds and didn't think they would be feasible performance-wise. I have not used SpriteKit before this project so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would use emitters to achieve that effect

Comment: Don't think they would work performance wise (See edit at bottom of post)

Comment: I agree if there are a lot of comets that emitters would not be a good choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a problem for a custom shader attached to the comet path. If you are not familiar with [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) in SpriteKit it lets you jump right into the GPU fragment shader specifically to control the drawing behavior of the nodes it is attached to [via SKShader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKShader).

Conveniently the **SKShapeNode** has a **strokeShader** property for hooking up an **SKShader** to draw the path. When connected to this property the shader gets passed the length of the path and the point on the path currently being drawn in addition to the color value at that point.*

*controlFadePath.fsh*

```
void main() {

  //uniforms and varyings
  vec4  inColor = v_color_mix;
  float length = u_path_length;
  float distance = v_path_distance;
  float start = u_start;
  float end = u_end;

  float mult;

  mult = smoothstep(end,start,distance/length);
  if(distance/length > start) {discard;}

  gl_FragColor = vec4(inColor.r, inColor.g, inColor.b, inColor.a) * mult;
}
```

To control the fade along the path pass a start and end point into the custom shader using two SKUniform objects named `u_start` and `u_end` These get added to the custom shader during initialization of a custom SKShapeNode class CometPathShape and animated via a custom Action.

*class CometPathShape:SKShapeNode*

```
class CometPathShape:SKShapeNode {

  //custom shader for fading
  let pathShader:SKShader
  let fadeStartU = SKUniform(name: "u_start",float:0.0)
  let fadeEndU = SKUniform(name: "u_end",float: 0.0)
  let fadeAction:SKAction

  override init() {
    pathShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "controlFadePath.fsh")

    let fadeDuration:NSTimeInterval = 1.52
    fadeAction = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(fadeDuration, actionBlock:
      { (node:SKNode, time:CGFloat)->Void in
            let D = CGFloat(fadeDuration)
            let t = time/D
            var Ps:CGFloat = 0.0
            var Pe:CGFloat = 0.0

            Ps = 0.25 + (t*1.55)
            Pe = (t*1.5)-0.25

            let comet:CometPathShape = node as! CometPathShape
            comet.fadeRange(Ps,to: Pe) })

    super.init()

    path = makeComet...(...)   //custom method that creates path for comet shape 

    strokeShader = pathShader
    pathShader.addUniform(fadeStartU)
    pathShader.addUniform(fadeEndU)
    hidden = true
    //set up for path shape, eg. strokeColor, strokeWidth...
    ...
  }

  func fadeRange(from:CGFloat, to:CGFloat) {
    fadeStartU.floatValue = Float(from)
    fadeEndU.floatValue = Float(to)     
  }

  func launch() {
    hidden = false
    runAction(fadeAction, completion: { ()->Void in self.hidden = true;})
  }
```

...

The SKScene initializes the CometPathShape objects, caches and adds them to the scene. During `update:` the scene simply calls `.launch()` on the chosen CometPathShapes.

*class GameScene:SKScene*

```
...
  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.name = "theScene"
    ...

    //create a big bunch of paths with custom shaders
    print("making cache of path shape nodes")
    for i in 0...shapeCount {
      let shape = CometPathShape()
      let ext = String(i)
      shape.name = "comet_".stringByAppendingString(ext)
      comets.append(shape)
      shape.position.y = CGFloat(i * 3)
      print(shape.name)
      self.addChild(shape)
    }

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    //pull from cache and launch comets, skip busy ones
    for _ in 1...launchCount {
        let shape = self.comets[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(shapeCount)))]
        if shape.hasActions() { continue }
        shape.launch()
    }
}
```

This cuts the number of SKNodes per comet from 3 to 1 simplifying your code and the runtime environment and it opens the door for much more complex effects via the shader. The only drawback I can see is having to learn some GLSL.**

*not always correctly in the device simulator. Simulator not passing distance and length values to custom shader.

**that and some idiosyncrasies in CGPath glsl behavior. Path construction is affecting the way the fade performs. Looks like `v_path_distance` is not blending smoothly across curve segments. Still, with care constructing the curve this should work.

Comment: Intersting. This uses less nodes, but would it be able to handle up to 50+ comets per second?

Comment: Only one way to find out... but since it is going right to the GL draw commands it should be the fastest way possible.

Comment: I am still getting up to speed with swift and scene kit but slapping something together using the above frag shader that adds 15 animating SKShapeNode lines a frame resultis in ~330 nodes rendering at ~11.5 fps on an old mini iPad and a iPhone 4S ... seems it should handle 50 comets a second just fine.

Comment: How did you set up the GLSL code? We tried a ton of different combinations but they all looked terrible. It seems really unreliable, the comet was growing from both ends and stuff (which is far from what the code intended, even in simplest cases)

Comment: I see now what the animation should do... I was picturing a faded path moving, but you want  the fade moving down the path (I think)... let me work on that a bit.

Comment: got it working. editing answer with correct solution.

Comment: Ill check this out tomorrow morning

Comment: I haven't (and probably won't) have time to check this out. We ended up using core animation but I'll flag this as correct since I trust that it works

Comment: Curious how you did it... did you drop SpriteKit or mix views? Anyway thanks for the checkmark!

Comment: We are still using SpriteKit for the background (since other parts are still in SpriteKit) but the comets are drawn entirely in CA. It was harder than expected (mostly due to multiple coordinate systems) but works!

Comment: Is it possible to simplify/change your code? I just spent an hour trying to get it to work and have not yet succeeded in seeing anything on the screen. Does the custom animation actually move the comet at all? It seems it should be much simpler than this

Comment: don't know if this matters but this targets iOS 8.1     Awww snap! looks like it does matter. **The nodes that look fine in 8.1 are not rendering on 9.2 !?!** #@%!  Sorry, no way to test without major update to my system...and this may force my hand.   :-(

Comment: Sorry mate, looks like Apple did let some bugs into the glsl with 9.x though the ones listed should not effect this particular shader it is possible there are other similar bugs without any chatter on SO. What is the debug output from your try?

Comment: yeah. Apple has apparently fragged custom shader behavior. One thing they did is make Metal the default. This can be fixed by adding **PrefersOpenGL = YES** to app's *Info.plist*. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem here which is _u_path_length_ and _v_path_distance_ appear to **not be working**, which pretty much makes this shader, or any path based custom shader, useless. Will update if I find a work around or fix. *Thanks Apple!*

Comment: 9 years later and I'm pleased to report that at some point, Apple fixed it.  I had all sorts of trouble initially, thinking the bugs were still there.  But I was also applying a dashed path which breaks what this answer offers.  Doing the dashes as part of the shader works a treat.  The `v_path_distance` and `u_path_length` variables work a treat.